# Create trigger based off CTE? Possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, common-table-expression, eventtrigger

I have a dataset which uses 3 tables.

For example

```
Select * 
FROM Apples as 1
INNER JOIN Oranges as 2
ON (1.ID = 2.ID)
INNER JOIN Bananas as  3
ON (1.ID = 3.ID)
```

I'm trying to create a trigger from this dataset. Anytime any of the columns in this dataset has been updated, deleted, or inserted I need to create an audit trail for this.

Keep in mind I cannot create any tables on the server. So creating an actual table out of the query above is not an option.  So my initial thought was to create a CTE for this dataset.

Then create a trigger as following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [schema_name.]trigger_name


ON >>>INSERT CTE HERE<<<


AFTER  {[INSERT],[UPDATE],[DELETE]}
AS
{sql_statements}
```

However I was told I cannot use a CTE for a trigger in this method...

Any ideas how do I solve for this?

Comment: No, this doesn't work, regardless of the database.  You might consider asking a *new* question, with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the trigger is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Updated my question for more context :)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Make it easy (and possible) to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Microsoft Sql Server

Comment: How about a trigger on each of the 3 tables you care about?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a CTE for this.  You use a *view*.

This would be an `instead of` trigger, and it would (generally) do updates on the relevant underlying tables.

This is well-documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Note that for some views, you can update the view directly, not having to rely on a trigger.